# Adding a weblink in Views

Tags: react-native

I am creating my first `React-Native` project and I intend to add a link in my views.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
   style={redditMain} > 
     <Image 
      source={ this.image }
       style={img} />
     <Text style={RedditList}>{this.text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I went through the [React-Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) which I am thinking talks about how we can achieve this and In that they have wrote this in their documentation

*To start the [corresponding activity for a link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking#opening-external-links) (web URL, email, contact etc.), call*

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

So I changed my code accordingly to this

```
  <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => {Linking.openURL('http://www.google.com/')}}
   style={redditMain} > 
    <Image 
     source={ this.image }
     style={img}
       /> 
     <Text style={RedditList}>{this.text}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

So whenever I click it starts throwing the following error

> Linking is not defined

**[Question:]** How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```